# Case senstive in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have this query

```
$query->orWhere(['order_delivery_address_city' => 'London']);
```

How to add parameter to the query, when city in database like 'london' (lower case), string not added in gridview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for an exact match for the string  you can use  BINARY

eg using the yii2 operator notation you could

```
$query->orWhere(['= BINARY', 'order_delivery_address_city', 'London'])
```

or LIKE

```
$query->orWhere(['LIKE BINARY', 'order_delivery_address_city', 'London'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
$query->orWhere(['LIKE','order_delivery_address_city','London']);
```